# Discrepancy between the results of NDSolve and DSolve (equations related to one step processes)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1**

---

The following are the dimensionless equations of a one-step random walk with an "impure" reflecting boundary assuming only four possible states, i.e., n=0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

[image: Equations]
On plugging in the equations with suitable initial conditions into Mathematica and using DSolve to solve the equations:

```
  sol = DSolve[{(p0'[t] == -2*p0[t] + p1[t]), (p1'[t] == 
      2*p0[t] + p2[t] - 2*p1[t]),  (p2'[t] == 
      p1[t] + p3[t] - 2*p2[t]), p0[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0, p2[0] == 1, 
    p3[0] == 0, p0[t] + p1[t] + p2[t] + p3[t] == 1}, {p0[t], p1[t], 
    p2[t], p3[t]}, {t}];

   Plot[Evaluate[{p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(0\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)(t)"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}]
```

It took a while but I got the plots. Then, I tried doing the same with NDSolve,

```
numericirb = 
  NDSolve[{(p0'[t] == -2*p0[t] + p1[t]), (p1'[t] == 
      2*p0[t] + p2[t] - 2*p1[t]),  (p2'[t] == 
      p1[t] + p3[t] - 2*p2[t]), p0[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0, p2[0] == 1, 
    p3[0] == 0, p0[t] + p1[t] + p2[t] + p3[t] == 1}, {p0[t], p1[t], 
    p2[t], p3[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[{p0[t] /. numericirb, p1[t] /. numericirb, p2[t] /. numericirb, 
  p3[t] /. numericirb}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(0\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)(t)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)(t)"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}]
```

Here are the plots from both the outputs:

[image: Plot from DSolve]

[image: Plot from NDSolve]

I do not understand why is there a discrepancy since the equations plugged in are identical? What am I missing here? I am using version 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) on Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.4

Comment: In v9.0.1, the plots are the same as your second plot. Which version are you in?

Comment: 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit). Also I'm sorry about the inefficient code used for plotting. Is there any error there?

Comment: It's a bug. You can substitute back the DSolve solution and see that the equations are not satisfied.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** This is a bug in version 12.0.0.

---

When there is a discrepancy between the symbolic and the numeric result, the symbolic one is *usually* (not always) incorrect. To make sure, the result can always be substituted back to verify it.

Here's a simpler and more concise way to write the problem:

```
eqn = {
   p0'[t] == -2*p0[t] + p1[t],
   p1'[t] == 2*p0[t] + p2[t] - 2*p1[t],
   p2'[t] == p1[t] + p3[t] - 2*p2[t],
   p0[0] == 0, p1[0] == 0, p2[0] == 1, p3[0] == 0,
   p0[t] + p1[t] + p2[t] + p3[t] == 1
   };

funs = {p0, p1, p2, p3};

sol = DSolve[eqn, funs, t];

nsol = NDSolve[eqn, funs, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Plotting:

```
Plot[{p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> funs, PlotRange -> All] (* symbolic *)

Plot[{p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]} /. nsol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> funs, PlotRange -> All] (* numeric *)
```

Let's verify the symbolic solution by back-substitution.

```
Table[
  (Subtract @@@ eqn) /. First[sol] /. t -> tt,
  {tt, 0., 10}
  ] // Chop

(*

{{0, 1., -3., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.367879, -1.73576, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0.135335, -1.27067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.0497871, -1.09957,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.0183156, -1.03663, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0.00673795, -1.01348, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.00247875, -1.00496, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.000911882, -1.00182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0.000335463, -1.00067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.00012341, -1.00025, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.0000453999, -1.00009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

*)
```

If the solution is correct, this should have yielded all zeros.

---

It turns out that the solution is correct and simple in version 11.3.  It is also correct in version 12.1.0, but it is not simple at all. In fact, the result I get is so large that I needed to use the options `MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 30` be able to plot it in a reasonable amount of time.

For reference, the solution returned by 11.3 is:

```
{{p0 -> Function[{t}, (1/
    4950967)(707281 + 
      67355776 RootSum[7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
        E^(t #1)/(14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      34933554 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (2 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      45308334 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (3 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      12615345 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (5 E^(t #1) + 2 E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      16270472 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         2 E^(t #1) + 4 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      16977753 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         6 E^(t #1) + 5 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &])], 
  p1 -> Function[{t}, (1/
    4950967)(1414562 + 
      83950995 RootSum[7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
        E^(t #1)/(14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      46111767 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (2 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      53965202 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (3 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      16881210 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (5 E^(t #1) + 2 E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      23787142 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         2 E^(t #1) + 4 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      25201704 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         6 E^(t #1) + 5 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &])], 
  p2 -> Function[{t}, (1/
    4950967)(1414562 - 
      26090495 RootSum[7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
        E^(t #1)/(14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      15412277 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (2 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      20106239 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (3 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      5124060 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (5 E^(t #1) + 2 E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      2725034 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         2 E^(t #1) + 4 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      6261439 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         6 E^(t #1) + 5 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &])], 
  p3 -> Function[{t}, (1/
    4950967)(1414562 - 
      125216276 RootSum[7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 
        E^(t #1)/(14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      65633044 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (2 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      79167297 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (3 E^(t #1) + E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      24372495 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (5 E^(t #1) + 2 E^(t #1) #1)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] - 
      37332580 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         2 E^(t #1) + 4 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &] + 
      35918018 RootSum[
        7 + 14 #1 + 7 #1^2 + #1^3 &, (
         6 E^(t #1) + 5 E^(t #1) #1 + E^(t #1) #1^2)/(
         14 + 14 #1 + 3 #1^2) &])]}}
```